# Big-O - what about the small values?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

So the big-O tells you something about the worst-case performance **when n (the input size) is sufficiently large**, like [image]. But what about the part where n is not that large? Don't we care about that?

Comment: Big O notation is mathematical concept. Mathematicians usually don't bother with small numbers :)

Comment: But when talking about complexities of algorithms, wouldn't it be nice to also know about the performance with smaller input sizes?

Comment: If it really matters, you can always say that complexity is O(g(n)) for n <= n0 and O(h(n)) for n > n0

Comment: This question is only indirectly related to programming as is, right? Have you considered to post this to https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Comment: I think this question is too broad for s-o. It's asking for reasons on why people use big-O when it has some flaws as a metric. But there's no one answer to that -- it's a combination of convenience, practical usefulness (despite the theoretical problems), popularity, and history. And there's some critics of big-O: Knuth and Sedgewick are significant CS names who prefer other measures. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hz95qqOdx0 is one critical discussion (Sedgewick).

Answer (score 1):

There is a load of factors which must be taken into account for small input sizes in real-world scenarios. Actually factoring them in would bloat the analysis. So, in contemporary reality, you are either satisfied with big O, which is a tip of the iceberg, or dig further armed with knowledge of the use case details, which are non-universal anyway.